# numpy array lookup table

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sorting, numpy-ndarray

hey i like to sort my array by the next way:
by col_index and unique value.
example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[21,30,105,1],[1,21,5,1],[5,15,20,1],[7,3,31,2]])
  #print:
  #[[ 21  30 105   1]
  #[  1   21 5    1]
  #[  5  15  20   1]
  #[  7   3  31   2]]
```

my wish to make new array with all the rows who have '1'(unique value) in the 4th (like a[0][3],a[1][3] and a[2][3]) and with value that bigger than 20 for 2th col (like a[0][1] and a[1][1])

for my example my wish to get:

```
new_a = np.array([[21,30,105,1],[1,21,5,1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
res = a[(a[:, 3] == 1) & (a[:, 1] > 20)]

# array([[ 21,  30, 105,   1],
#        [  1,  21,   5,   1]])
```

Comment: @NewCoder, Feel free to accept (tick on left) if this solves your problem.